# Impala - how to set a variable in a query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

How can I set a variable in an Impala query?

In SQL:

```
select * from users where id=(@id:=123)
```

In Impala:

```
impala-shell> ?
```

Impala version is v2.0.0. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: From which dialect of SQL are you taking that variable definition syntax? From what I can tell the only symbol in the SQL standard for bind parameters is "?".

Comment: The ':=' assignment is from MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value

Answer (score 5):

```
impala-shell> set var:id=123;select * from users where id=${VAR:id};
```

This variable can also be passed from command-line using `--var`

```
impala-shell --var id=123
impala-shell> select * from users where id=${VAR:id};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an open feature request for adding variable substitution support to impala-shell: [IMPALA-1067](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1067), to mimic Hive's similar feature (`hive --hivevar param=60` substitutes `${hivevar:param}` inside a query with `60`).

Variables that you can use in other SQL contexts (e.g. from a JDBC client) are not supported either, and I couldn't even find an open request for it... You might want to open a request for it: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA

Answer (score 0):

```
impala-shell -i node.domain:port -B --var"table=metadata" --var="db=transaction" -f "file.sql"
```

file.sql:

> SELECT * FROM ${var:db}.${var:table}"